# Using importXML in in Google Sheets to pull data under a "b class"

Tags: google-sheets, google-chrome, importxml, xpath

Looking at this page: https://www.mycryptobuddy.com/BitcoinMiningCalculator/path?hashrate=110&powerCost=0.059&power=3250&hardwareCost=4050

There is a line that says "Profitable in 10 Months 14 Days", I wanted to pull the "10 Months 14 Days" to a Google Sheet.

When I inspect the HTML code, this is what came up:

[image: screen shot]

so I used this:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.mycryptobuddy.com/BitcoinMiningCalculator/path?hashrate=110&powerCost=0.059&power=3250&hardwareCost=4050", "//div//h4//b[class='ng-binding']")
```

But it is not working unfortunately. I spent hours trying to figure it out and changing it and I managed to pull different things. Any ideas?

Edit 1: I saw the answers before my question was migrated and I cannot see them again after migration. Thank you to the people that took the time to explain to me.
I tried disabling Java and the content I am looking to import into sheets did not disappear:[image]

I tried HTML variations with no luck so I edited the IMPORTXML code to this:

```
`=IMPORTXML("https://www.mycryptobuddy.com/BitcoinMiningCalculator/path?hashrate=110&powerCost=0.059&power=3250&hardwareCost=4050", "//div//h4//b")`
```

Which led to this import into Google Sheets (not N/A) :
{{breakeven | breakevenFilter}}

Is it time to give up or am I one step away from getting what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. The xpath shown by the Inspector tool corresponds to the element from the DOM that might have being modified dynamically.

Comment: It looks that "10 Months 13 Days" is added dynamically. Forget about using IMPORTXML to import this text.